# Segmentation error with a list iterator

Tags: c++

```
class Line{
    list<char> line;

    char getChar(const int position) const {
         std::list<char>::const_iterator itr;
         itr = line.begin();
         for (int i = 0; i< position; i++){
            itr++;
         }
         return *itr;//according to the debugger this is where the error happens.
}
```

So this is a function that is called a LOT in my program, however in a specific instance, it is called and it results in a segmentation error. What could possibly cause this?

This is how its called:

```
    std::list<Line>::const_iterator itr;
    itr = file.begin();// file is a list of Lines, line 1 characters 0-4 are all spaces.
    while (itr != file.end()) {
         int i = 0;//this works with 0 but anything else it gets a segmentation error.
        while ((*itr).getChar(i) != '\n') {//This is where it errors.
```

This is something that has popped up a few times but for the life of me i cant remember how i fixed it. I just dont understand how it can be getting an error like this when this function has been called multiple times in EXTREMELY similar circumstances.

Comment: `(*itr).getChar(i)` -- seems like you never heard of the `->` operator? `itr->getChar(i)` is much more readable and idiomatic. And what a `Line` is at all?

Comment: It looks like you are simply accessing elements outside of the valid range. As a simple improvement, add `assert(itr != line.end());` in your loop directly after `itr++` and see if it fires.

Comment: or use safer functions such as `std::find` to find the item.

Comment: Line just hold a list of characters and some functions to read them. I started using off using '->' but it kept giving me: base operand of `->' has non-pointer type `const Line'

Comment: @tillaert  std::find only works here if i force it to fail to find, so that it returns the last value in the range. Is there a std function that will return a value at a given position?

Comment: @user3593486 No, because you can't access a value that is out of range. If you get an iterator to `end()`, then it is not there, if you get a different iterator, you can get the range in front of that iterator by using it as a range.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a line in your file that only has a newline character in it, this will cause a segmentation fault. If you pass in 1, it will try to access the thing at position 1 in the line. But the `\n` character is at position 0.

Comment: Its giving me the error on line 1, character 1, which is a space.

Answer (score 0):

If your first line is a single space, you will get a segmentation fault as soon as you get an index (`i`) beyond 0 in your implementation. You are advancing the iterator beyond the length of the container (past the end of the list).

You can use some standard STL, it will throw an exception as soon as you advance beyond the end of the container (which will give you more information that a seg fault):

```
class Line{
    list<char> line;
    char getChar(const int position) const {
        auto itr = line.begin();
        advance(itr,position);    
        return (*itr);        
    }
};
```

If you are not using C++11 change the `auto` to `std::list<char>::iterator`. If you want to silently stop the client from getting a position beyond the end (which I do not recommend) : `advance(itr,(position > line.size()-1) ? line.size()-1 : position);` (also might want to check that position is positive or make it an unsigned int).

Also I am not sure why you are using a `list` unless your doing a lot of splicing across the lines. I recommend using a `vector<char>` if your lines contain a lot of characters (use `reserve` if you know the length) or simply a `std::string`.

```
string abcd = "abcd";    
cout << abcd.at(0) << endl;
cout << abcd[0] << endl;
cout << abcd.at(4) << endl;
```

the exception will be more useful:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string
```

Comment: just before you commented i changed it to use the std::advance function but it didnt help.(still segmentation error) If it helps the debugger (GDB)keeps saying: "no symbol 'case' in current context" before the error signal is sent.

Comment: that error usually means that the `case` variable has been optimized out out of existence (unused?) or assigned to a register (not memory) by gdb. It could be unrelated. I see two ways it could seg fault on that line: a) (*itr) is invalid b) your i is greater than or equal to the number of characters on that line. Check that your list is not `empty()` and that you are not increasing `itr` before the second `while`. Also check incrementing beyond the end of the line (try that silent ignore I suggest to pinpoint it).

Comment: I am way too tired, turns out the list is somehow empty. Sorry for wasting everyones time, i should have picked up on that.